# Organize x-axis to make chart look better

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The x-axis is the value ranging from 0 to 3000, and each x has corresponding y value. However, the result chart is not easy to visualize each point properly.

[image]

Any idea on how to organize the x-axis to make it not too messy? Thank you!

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(value,color = 'g',linestyle = '--')
ax1.set_xlim(0,3000)
```

Comment: There are too many ways to change the look of the graph. Is there something specific you are aiming for? You should consider what exactly you are trying to convey.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I want to group the x-axis. Now my x-axis range from 0 to 3000. I want to group each values for each 100 bucket. So that for x=100, I only have 1 value, and for x=200, I have 1 value and so on. Any idea on how to achieve?

Comment: Seems you just want to downsample your data? There are numerous ways to do this--many you can find on this site. Perhaps simplest is to bin your data and average: reshape your data into a 2d array with 100 in the last dimension then average along this last dimension.